# Reversing words in a string using three pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, pointers

I am trying to reverse words in a string and I believe that I have written the right logic, but while debugging I came to know that the value that I am putting in `new_array` char pointer variable is getting lost? And I don't seem to have any idea why?

Can you tell me what is the mistake I am doing and what can be done to correct it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_words(char *arr, int size) {
    char *ptr = arr;
    char *new_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);

    while (*ptr != '\0') {
        ptr++;
    }
    ptr--;

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (*ptr != ' ') {
            ptr--;
        } else {
            char *temp = ptr;
            temp++;
            //
            // Problem is in this block new_array value is lost when i increment it                                
            while (*temp != ' ' && *temp != '\0') {
                *new_array = *temp;
                new_array++;
                temp++;
            }
            if (i != 0) {
                *new_array = *ptr;
                ptr--;
            }
        }
    }
    *new_array = '\0';
    strcpy(arr, new_array);
    return;
}

int main() {
    char arr[] = "My job is coding";
    int size = sizeof(arr);
    reverse_words(arr, size);
    printf("%s", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "lost"?

Comment: The value is not there, that i put using *temp;

Comment: @user3405439 don't do new_array++  bcz when loop fails new_array points to NULL and you are copying NULL to arr

Comment: Code that increments `new_array` changes its value.   That is what incrementing does.  You can't expect, in later code, that `new_array` will magically have reverted to its original value.    BTW: if all you are trying to do is reverse a string in place, a `malloc()` call is unnecessary.

Comment: Note: you don't need to allocate a copy of the string.You can reverse in-place,  swapping only characters.

Comment: BTW:do you need to reverse the order of the words, or do you need to reverse the characters inside the words, maintaining the order of the words?

Comment: i need to reverse order of words output should be "coding is job my"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated and has several problems:

- you allocate too much memory: `(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);` allocates `size` times the size of a pointer.  Use `malloc(size);` to allocate `size` bytes.
- there are errors in your pointer manipulations,
- you forget to free the allocated memory, causing a memory leak.
- you do not need to pass the size of the array, the length of the string is computed by scanning for the null terminator, just allocate one extra byte for the null terminator.

There is an alternative solution to reverse the words int the string in place without memory allocation:

- for each word, reverse the word
- final step: reverse the string

Here is the code using a utility function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse_mem(char *str, int size) {
    for (int i = 0, j = size; i < --j; i++) {
        char c = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = c;
    }
}

void reverse_words(char *arr) {
     for (int i = 0, j = 0;; i = j) {
        for (; str[i] == ' '; i++)
            continue;
        if (str[i] == '\0')
            break;
        for (j = i; str[j] != '\0' && str[j] != ' '; j++)
            continue;
        reverse_mem(str + i, j - i);
    }
    reverse_mem(str, size);
}

int main(void) {
    char arr[] = "My job is coding";
    reverse_words(arr);
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not getting output as expected because of this statement ..

```
*new_array = *temp; //2nd time new_array is not pointing previous location  so how will you retrieve data 
   new_array++;// you lost previous data bcz pointers no longer holds previous address
```

when main loop fail new_array pointer will point to last but it should holds starting address. Instead of incrementing `new_array` directly do like

```
* (new_array + j) =  *temp
```

I modified your code as . .

```
void reverse_words(char *arr,int size)
{
        char * ptr = arr;
        char *new_array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
        printf("initial : %u \n",ptr);
        while(*ptr != '\0')
        {
                ptr++;
        }
        int j=0;
        ptr--;
        printf("first : %c : %u  \n",*ptr,ptr);
        for(int i = size-1;i >=0;i--)
        {
                if(*ptr != ' ' ) //&& i!=0)
                {
                        ptr--;//from last to back

                }
                else
                {
                        char * temp = ptr;
                        temp++;
                        while(*temp != '\0' && *temp!=' ')
                        {
                                new_array[j++]=*temp;
                                temp++;

                        }
                        if(i!=0)
                        {
                                new_array[j++] = *ptr;
                                ptr--;
                        }
                }

        }
        new_array[j] = '\0';
        printf("new = %s \n",new_array);
        strcpy(arr,new_array);

}
```

I hope you got where it's going wrong, Modify the condition for `first` words because once `i` becomes `0` you are not writing any logic for that.

My Solution according to your requirements

```
void reverse_words(char *arr,int size) {
        char *new_array = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
        int i,j,k=0;
        for(i = size-1 ;i >= -1 ; i--) {
                if(arr[i] ==' ' || i == -1)
                {
                        for(j=i+1;arr[j]!=' ' && arr[j]!='\0'; j++)
                                new_array[k++] = arr[j];
                        new_array[k++] = ' ';
                }
        }
        new_array[k] = '\0';
        strcpy(arr,new_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but isn't it like contigous storage is allocated to new_array, or i am trying the change the base address of new_array? can you please explain?

Comment: @user3405439 yes you are trying to change base address of new_array.